# Pass command to powershell start-Process in Argument-List

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I want to pass a cmdlet to be executed immediately in child Process.

---> `$cmd = $(Get-Item -FORCE "PATH\to\Folder").Attributes= "Normal"`

```
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList " multiple $cmd Here"
```

PS : when i use `{ }` , `()` or `" "` in -ArgumentList i get different behaviour anyone care to explain why ?.

Comment: Why do you use the parameter `-argumentlist` if you only want to execute a command? Just use the parameter `-command` instead?

Comment: @guiwhatsthat how so ?

Comment: Like that: `$Items = powershell.exe -command {Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp"}`

Comment: thank you for the input, but i need the new powershell process to be a child process and not a separate one.

Comment: Have you looked into `Invoke-Command -AsJob` or `Start-Job` ?

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. This looks very much like an [XY-problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).